# How should I setup a WinForms desktop app for remote use within an intranet?

Tags: .net, winforms, desktop-application, remote-access

I have to write a desktop app that resides on a server on the domain. Some clients on the LAN are PC's, some are Macs.

- What are some ways I can setup the environment for the users to use the app?
- Is click-once deployment still a viable option in .NET 4.x?
- And what about for the Mac users?

Comment: If RDP is an option, you could install the app on the server and allow both Windows and Mac clients to access via RDP.  Licensing considerations may make this impossible, but thought I would throw out the option.

Comment: Thanks Eric. The bigger issue is that multiple people will be connected at the same time. Isn't there a limit to the number of people that can RDP to a server at once?

Answer (score 1):

The question is too general, but I'll try to give some tips

1. This is app on server. The best way to use this for clients - to have *client* apps that can connect to the server and ask for information or sent it commands.
2. ClickOnce works almost as before, changes are mentioned in the [article](http://robindotnet.wordpress.com/2010/05/23/whats-new-in-clickonce-deployment-in-net-4-0/)
3. If you follow first answer, there is no problem to implement mac client too. You may use [mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) for it, or use platform-independent network protocol (http is the example), or webservices as a start point

Comment: Thanks for the details Anton! Budget was limited. So creating "clients" wouldn't be feasible. Had there been a larger budget, I would've built it as a web app and done away with this problem altogether. Further thoughts are appreciated.